# Trimming text SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a data field being output into a report that gives me, for example:

'Reference Number: **878655555**   detail, detail, lots of text etc'

Basically the only text I want to show in my report is the number in bold.

Please can someone advise how to use LEFT and RIGHT (or some other function) to remove superfluous text either side of the data I want to output? I've tried a few combinations but nothing's worked so far.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there always a space after the text "Number:" and before the number in bold? and is there always a space after the number in bold and before the next word?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Yes, there is always a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=Mid(Fields!my.Value,InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+1
        ,Instr(InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+3,Fields!my.Value," ") - 
            InStr(Fields!myValue,":") -1)`

did the trick, inspired by Mazhar's post

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always 9 digits long then try this using `MID` and `InStr`

```
=Mid(Fields!YourField.Value, InStr(Fields!YourField.Value, ": ")+2, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mazhar. What you posted directly led to me being able to solve it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help @WillF